# Seek Time vs Transfer Rate

Tags: big-data, hadoop

Estava lendo um pouco a respeito da ferramenta Hadoop para big data e me deparei com os termos Seek Time e Transfer Rate. Encontrei definições do tipo Seek Time é o delay para encontrar um arquivo/dado especifico e Transfer Rate é a velocidade para encontrar o arquivo/dado porém não estou muito satisfeito com as respostas que achei e não estou certo de que elas estejam certas.

Então gostaria de saber se alguém possui definições mais detalhadas a respeito dos dois termos e conseguiria responder essas dúvidas.

1. **O que é Seek Time e Transfer Rate?**
2. **Qual é a real diferença entre eles ?**
3. **E quando é melhor usar um e quando é melhor usar o outro ?**

Comment: nesse caso o mais importante e o tranfer, onde o MapReduce se baseia na velocidade aos dados.

Answer (score 0):

Seek Time é o delay (o tempo que leva) para que o sistema encontre o arquivo (posicione o head de read/write no arquivo).

Transfer Rate, no contexto de throughtput, é a velocidade de leitura ou escrita desse arquivo.

Ambos são úteis e medem coisas distintas.

RDBMS por ser baseado em B-Tree, é altamente dependente de operações de Seek e por isso é mais eficiente para atualizar pequenas porções em grandes conjuntos de dados.

Já o MapReduce utiliza operações de SORT e Merge para recriar dados, o que acaba sendo mais dependente de Transfer.

Como o Transfer é mais rápido que o Seek e tem evoluído devido ao surgimento de novas tecnologias, o MapReduce é mais indicado para uso em cenários de BigData.